# write() в Python автоматически переносит последнюю кавычку

Tags: python

Файл firstMeeting.py

```
def getUserName():
    resultName = nameInput.get("1.0", "end")
    file = open("settings.py", "a")
    file.write(f"\nfirstStart = False\nuserName = '{resultName}'")
    file.close()
    print(resultName)
```

Файл settings.py (До записи данных)

```
title = "Main window"
width = 500
height = 800
firstStart = True
```

Файл settings.py (После записи данных)

```
title = "Main window"
width = 500
height = 800
firstStart = True
firstStart = False
userName = '123
'
```

Почему write() после записи данных автоматически переносит последнюю кавычку?
И можно ли изменить способ записи переменных firstStart и userName?

Comment: Потому что в resultName есть символ переноса строки, видимо

Comment: `resultName.strip()`

Comment: совет: в f строках для создания строки вида `s={s}` можно использовать `{s=}` так будет короче. также если в `s` строка то кавычки появятся автоматически